# Unit Testing - Extending the Visual Studio Unit Test Type - Not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

We're asked to move from NUnit to MSTest and now have to convert all the existing tests to the new platform.  Most of it converted fine but we have an issue with parameterised tests. We found the following web site showing how to write an extension and downloaded the code for it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-2.aspx

However, although it compiles fine, the RowTestClass test all fail to run with the following error message:

> "Failed to initialize the unit test extension 'urn:RunAsTestClassAttribute': A unit test extension is not registered for the following attribute: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Test.Sample.UnitTestTypeExtension.RunAsSample.RunAsTestClassAttribute."

We're using VS2010 (10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel) (Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel)

I wonder if it has something to do with the following libraries:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll
Runtime Version: v2.0.50727

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
Runtime Version: v4.0.30319

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Vsip.dll
v4.0.30319

C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Vsip\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Vsip.dll
```

Any help to get this working greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to pass a parameter into your unit test method?

Comment: Basically not to have to repeat the same code for each test parameter. It keeps the code cleaner by avoiding having to use logic like loops with if or switch statements or creating dependencies to external files or database.

Comment: I would have the test method call another non-test method that accepts the parameters and does the appropriate assertions.

Comment: I know this can be done, but I think it's a bit messy doing it like this.  In NUnit we have TestCase which is a much cleaner way to test with parameters.  The Extension code is supposed to allow MSTest to do exactly the same thing but unfortunately I couldn't get the code to work yet.

Comment: Should not have moved to MSTest as MSTest is not really a true Unit Testing framwork IMO. http://osherove.com/blog/2011/8/24/why-mstest-is-the-ie6-of-unit-test-frameworks.html. I remember I tried this and it was a very painful to get it working. I had to play with PublicAssemblies Private Assemblies and windows registry. Not to say that couple of questions in MSDN forums. If I can find those links I will update the comment. If the MS tooling support is the reason to move to MSTest, I would not worry because VS2012 Test runner support NUnit plus many other test frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered the new types (in the [Windows Registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry))? There's a section on how to do it in [the tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-2.aspx) - have a look at ***Row Test Test Type Extension: Registering your test type extension***.

If you're having trouble, try downloading the complete code + registry keys from the [MSDN code gallery](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/UnitTestExtendSample).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/) to make your tests more parameterized.  It is traditionally a BDD tool, but it will allow you to make re-usable steps that take parameters.

For example you can create a step saying

```
"Given the user 'admin' exists."
```

and on the c# side you get a method like this:

```
[Given(@"the user '(.*)' exists"]
public void GivenTheUserExists(string name)
{
    //create the user
}
```

Going forward you can reuse the step in any "feature file" without having to rewrite the implementation of that step.

Comment: How does this answer the original question? Are you just advertising Specflow?

Comment: I was providing a seemingly less complex solution to parameterizing unit tests.  If that is advertising a free tool then yes i'm advertising it.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to the blog post *[Extending Unit Tests in Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/04/28/extending-unit-tests-in-visual-studio.aspx)*. And see what you might have missed. I tried the same, and it works well for me.